# Set Character sets for All Oracle Databases

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I'm using Oracle Database 12c on RHEL System, and I wanna to set the parameters **NLS_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8** and **NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET=AL16UTF16** by default for all created databases with sql create statement to avoid to add them every time when I issue the create query.
I have tried to add these parameters to **initSID.ora** but it seems they are not valid as initialization parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.  First, it would be unusual to have more than a couple Oracle databases on a server (ideally no more than 1) unless we're talking about a server that runs a bunch of VMs.  The database and national character set must be set when the database is created, not after in the pfile or spfile, though you probably can change the character set after a database is created.  You could modify whatever script you use to create new databases to specify the character set if your script doesn't already do so.  But I doubt that's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: character set is entered when you issue the command **CREATE DATABASE**. Either you use your own crafted scripts or DBCA tool. In case of DBCA simply create a template having the right charset specified